# I am black as night, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am black as night
>
> If you want I can help you take watch until first light
>
> I fit in every crevice and every hole
>
> After I get hot I then quickly get cold

**What am I?**

Comment: Any black liquid element with higher boiling point? :)

Comment: @Techidiot you are on the right track, however the boiling point is irrelevant.

Comment: I rephrased the second clue because it was a little to ambiguous

Comment: Some fuel perhaps?

Comment: @Gecko IT - How was boiling point irrelevant? If the boiling point is higher, the liquid cools down quickly at room temperature I guess.

Comment: @Techidiot the temperature drop is quick, but it doesn't state it is quicker or slower then anything else. It has to be interpreted more like a common knowledge, not like a scientific phenomenon.

Comment: If my answer (or something similar) is correct I am still a bit confused by the word "quickly" in the last line.

Comment: @oleslaw- That was the only thing which led me to believe it has something to do with boiling point. I might have went with Mercury. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> coffee!

I am black as night

> you are indeed

If you want I can help you take watch until first light

> helps not to fall asleep

I fit in every crevice and every hole

> As (almost) any liquid would

After I get hot I then quickly get cold

> It gets cold quicker than you would want it to :)

Comment: @Downvoter What is wrong with this answer? Comment to help me make it better.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the last part does matter  :) Thus a shadow I am not.

Comment: I know that it is most certainly not the intended answer, but at least it fits all the clues now :)

Comment: Water is indeed an answer in the right direction, but I rephrased the second clue a bit to help

Comment: @oleslaw- Tea can also be an answer :) Though +1. Should be correct.

Comment: Coffee was indeed the intended answer, but tea is correct as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Shadow/your shadow

You are black as night.

You can help me take watch till first light.

You fit everywhere.

Comment: How do I do spoilers?

Comment: Only the last clue is bugging me

Comment: Here's the relevant markdown for spoilers :
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers